# MethodAccessException on CF 2.0 List<T>.Sort

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I've got some [library code](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) that works on a range of .NET runtimes (regular, CF, Silverlight, etc) - but a small block of code is breaking **only** on CF 2.0, with a `MethodAccessException`. I'm pretty sure it is a runtime bug, but does anybody know any good workarounds? It works fine in CF 3.5, but I need to be able to support CF 2.0 too.

Specifically, this relates to a library assembly using generics, being given a non-public `T` by the caller. I don't do anything nasty to the `T` (such as reflection), but it breaks anyway...

All it does is wrap the values and add them to the list,
then sort the list via a `Comparison<>`. I have also tried `Array.Sort`,
`IComparer<Wrapper<T>>`, `IComparable<Wrapper<T>>`, etc - all
fail in the same way: `MethodAccessException` - 
with the VS tip:

> If the access level of a method in a
>   class library has changed, recompile
>   any assemblies that reference that
>   library.

But make the `T` public and it all works fine... note that we were never sorting on `T` - we were only working with `Wrapper<T>`...

Any input appreciated...

---

Library assembly:

```
public static class LibraryClass
{
    public static void Test<T>(T foo, T bar)
    {
        // vastly simplified... I am aware that it is already in order here ;-p
        var list = new List<Wrapper<T>>();
        list.Add(new Wrapper<T> { Tag = 1, Value = foo });
        list.Add(new Wrapper<T> { Tag = 2, Value = bar });

        list.Sort((x,y) => x.Tag.CompareTo(y.Tag)); // BOOM!!
    }
}

public class Wrapper<T> // public to prove this isn't a factor...
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public int Tag { get; set; }
}
```

---

Calling assembly:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyData foo = new MyData {Name = "foo"},
            bar = new MyData {Name = "bar"};

        LibraryClass.Test<MyData>(foo, bar);
    }
}

class MyData // but make MyData public and it works...
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Doh! Saw the question, immediately thought of referring to your blog post... then saw that you were the person asking it :(

Comment: hehe - I thought I'd pick the collective brain to see if anybody knows any tricks here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried writing your own sort - perhaps the built in one is doing some reflection shenanigans...  Not with a view to using your own in the long term - but as a means of debugging the problem.  It should be quick to code in something else and at least see whats then.

I presume you don't get a stack trace when it goes boom.

Comment: Indeed, no stack trace. I'd rather not have to re-write such a fundamental method, but the thought had occurred...

Comment: I guess (in the absense of any other replies) that re-writing sort will have to suffice...

Answer (score 0):

I remember having troubles (sometimes) to make sure that the right dotNET stuff is on the target device.  This was in dotNET CF 1.0 days.  Could this still be the issue here?

Comment: I don't think so - it is easy enough to show it working fine except for the specific use-case. Thanks, though.